# Video issue using iExplorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video

I wished to have my video thumbnail show up as the first frame of my video. My solution was to begin the video on frame1 rather than frame 0 (code is below). This works great in Firefox and Chrome but IE wants to initialize the video on frame 0 which is empty. Is there a workaround so that all three browsers show the first frame thumbnail. I did try poster and that didn't work correctly across all browsers either. Any help would be appreciated. I used #t=1 to access the first frame.

```
    <video style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block; padding-bottom: 2em;" width="640" height="360" controls >
        <source src="_videos/My_Video.mp4#t=1" type="video/mp4" >
    </video>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand that you want to show the 1st frame as a thumbnail for the video. but its looks like it is not supported in Internet Explorer.

You had mentioned that you already use the **poster** attribute to display the thumbnail of the video but it didn't work correctly. Can you inform us what problem you are facing with poster? I try to make a test with poster on my side and it looks like it is working with IE.

Sample code:

```html
<video controls
    src="https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4"
    poster="https://peach.blender.org/wp-content/uploads/title_anouncement.jpg?x11217"
    width="620">

Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos, 
but don't worry, you can <a href="https://archive.org/details/BigBuckBunny_124">download it</a> 
and watch it with your favorite video player!

</video>
```

Output:

[image]

Reference:

[: The Video Embed element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)